# Python: How to perform function on multiple files and combine results

Tags: python, arrays, file, function, compare

I am attempting to create a function which compares data from multiple files. The files are chosen through a dialog window (from GUI platform Tkinter)

```
def compare_datafiles(file_name): 
    data = np.genfromtxt(file_name, dtype=float, delimiter=',', skiprows=(2), usecols=(1,2,3,4,5,6), skip_footer=(3))
    initial = data[0,:]
    final = data[-1,:]
    weightDiff=final-initial  
    data=np.row_stack((data, weightDiff)) 
    totalWD=sum(data[4,:]) # calculate total weight
    distr=np.round((weightDiff/totalWD),2) 
    print distr
    return  distr   

for x in selectedFiles:
        M = compare_datafiles(x)
```

When I run the function with two input files, it prints two arrays:

```
runfile(r'C:\Users...)
    [ 0.23  0.04  0.1   0.14  0.12  0.38]
    [ 0.22  0.05  0.13  0.16  0.12  0.32]
```

But only returns one of them:

```
M
array([ 0.22,  0.05,  0.13,  0.16,  0.12,  0.32])
```

How can I get it to return both of the arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you write:

```
for x in selectedFiles:
    M = compare_datafiles(x)
```

You reassign to `M` on each loop, so only the last value is stored. You could make `M` a list and append to it, or use a list comprehension:

```
>>> M = [compare_datafiles(x) for x in selectedFiles]
```

Comment: Thank you, @miku. could you possible suggest a simple way of plotting the data obtained from the function, as separate arrays?

Comment: Here's how I did it:  `arrayNumber = range(0,len(selectedFiles))
for x in arrayNumber: 
    plt.plot(sizes,M[x],'-rs',markerfacecolor='none', linewidth='2')`

Comment: There are many plotting libraries for python, e.g. http://matplotlib.org/, https://github.com/yhat/ggplot/, http://gnuplot-py.sourceforge.net/ -